# To which file descriptor execve redirect?

Tags: c, io, fork

```
int main (void) {

   int rc=fork();
   if(rc==0){
   close(1); //close stdout BEFORE opening my file
   open("./c.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);


   //execve "wc"
   char *cmd[3];
   cmd[0] = strdup("wc"); //file to execuable
   cmd[1]=strdup("c.c"); //first arg to command 'wc' -> c.c
   cmd[2]=NULL;

   execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
   }
```

If I close() stdout, then the output of execve ("wc"), will be in file `c.txt` but ONLY if I close stdout BEFORE open()ing. If I call it AFTER

```
open("./c.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
   close(1);
```

then -> `wc: write error: Bad file descriptor`.

I have read, that for open() (probably in my case for `wc` output) is OS reaching file descriptor from 0, and so it first find `1` as stdout to printf() to screen. So I need to close() it, in order to use file descriptor from open("./c.txt") for `wc`. But If that is correct (I do not know where I have understood it correctly), then it would not matter whether I close stdout before or after open() call, does it? Once it is closed, OS has no other FD to use as output. I maybe does not understand it clearly.

question: why must be fd1 closed first in order to make redirection to c.txt?

Comment: Of course it matters. If you don't close it first then the `1` fd is still in use and `open` will not be able to return `1` as the new fd for the `open` of `c.txt`.

Comment: But how? I mean, execve looks for fd that is `closest` or, why? When the program reach the execve, the fd 1 is alreadu closed (whether before open or after). So how does execve decide what fd to use? I thought open() would not matter of decision of execve, but available FDs would. How is the decison made?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "`execve` looks for fd". It doesn't do that. What it does is create a new process with the same set of open fds as the parent process. That is, if `1` is open in the parent and is associated with `stdout` then the new process resulting from `execve` will see that open fd and association. If `1` is closed just before `execve` then there will be no fd `1` in the new process and hence the `bad file descriptor` error when `wc` tries to write to fd `1` (which is normally `stdout` but is redirected to `c.txt` in the correct version of your code).

Comment: There's actually more details than that as there are ways to change which fds remain open upon exevce. The details can be read from the [execve man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).

Comment: How is the redirection made? why doesn't use wc c.txt even if I closed the fd1 just before execve? why fd1 must be closed as first in order to make redirection?

Comment: Can't explain in a comment. I will try to write an answer. Though I'm not sure I can cover all the things you need explained as there are multiple concepts that you need to understand and I don't really know which parts you understand already and which not.

Comment: please answer as much detail as it could. I need to understand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few concepts to establish first.

1. `stdout` is one of the streams automatically opened as part of program startup. The program startup code uses file descriptor `1` for `stdout`).
2. `execve` creates a new process with the same open file descriptors as the parent/calling process (there are exceptions and naunces which can be read from the [execve man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).
3. `open` will look for the [lowest available file descriptor](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_14) to use.

Ok, so now to your code.

**Case 1 - close, open, execve**

In this case the following sequence of events happens:

1. Program starts with `stdout`=>`fd 1`.
2. `close(1)` makes `fd 1` available.
3. `open("c.txt")` returns `1` which effectively redirects `stdout` to the file.
4. `execve` creates a new process which has `1` open and redirected to the file.
5. `wc` writes to `fd 1` which now ends up in the file.

**Case 2 - open,close,execve**

In this case the following sequence of events happens:

1. Program starts with `stdout`=>`fd 1`.
2. `open("c.txt")`is called but `fd 1` is not available so it returns `2`.
3. `close(1)` means there is now effectively no `stdout`.
4. `execve` creates a new process which has no open stream on `fd 1` (ie no `stdout`).
5. `wc` tries to write to `fd 1` and gets a `bad file descriptor` error since `fd 1` is not open.

Comment: But why does open try to take the lowest fd, when I specifie the path of file in argument? I am explicitly telling the open() to give me a fd according to  the path, so why would it take fd1 for example instead? The argument the (file path) would not make sense then.

Comment: Meybe, the path does not matter? so if I close() fd1, then whatever path I specified, will get fd1?

Comment: And - if I have - for example - open()ed 5 files (that is having fd3-8, and clos()ed forexample fd5, then there os a hole among fds, and the next open() will take that fd5?

Comment: "I am explicitly telling the open() to give me a fd according to the path". That's not how `open` is defined to work. You give a path and `open` will do what it needs to to get the file ready for access and return to you an `fd` to use. Posix [specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_14) the `open` behaviour regarding using the lowest available fd. So yes, the path doesn't directly determine the fd returned. And yes if the next available fd is `5` then that is the one returned.

Comment: last question, but not about open, but exec. I am telling (secifically in my progrmm) the first argument as "wc", but the first argument requires path, that is (as I assume) full path to `usr/bin/wc`, so how does exec work in this case? it will translate it as bash does to the full path, or how?

Comment: Yes that's mostly it. For full details refer to the [execvp man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp): "The execlp(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions duplicate the actions of the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified filename does not contain a slash (/) character. The file is sought in the colon-separated list of directory pathnames specified in the PATH environment variable.".